# Property Setter and Method DRY

Tags: properties, methods, dry

When is it a good idea to make a Method wrappers for a Property Setters?

Example: Show and Hide are just wrappers for Visible = True and Visible = False, respectively.

Answer (score 0):

It's a good idea to do that if the method name better conveys the intent of the operation being performed.